# Disable scientific notation in Spark Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a table to consume from Spark and do data transformations.

There is a column that have values with 8 numbers after `.` something like this: `0.00000001`

This column have the absolute value like this number above.

I need to take the absolute value of that column, without let Spark transform this in scientific notation. When Spark reads the table, it transforms the column in scientific notation.

I have tried to convert in String, Double or Float, but nothing works. I need this field in the type Decimal. The type of the field is already Decimal natively in the column.

Is there some way to do this?

Code to simulate:

```
val df = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq((0.00000001))).toDF("Value")
```

Spark shows me this: `0E-8`

And i need this in Decimal Type: `0.00000001`

Thanks!

Comment: Is this only for showing results or converting to a string later on? Because the numbers are the exact same if you're using them in operations.

Comment: Actually i need to get the real value in a dataframe and then save in a avro file.
When i do this with the scientific notation, avro file gives me "null" on the field.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [format_number](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#format_number) function to get desired result.

```
spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq((0.00000001))).toDF("Value").
   selectExpr("format_number(Value,'#.########') as Value").show(false)

/*
+----------+
|Value     |
+----------+
|0.00000001|
+----------+*/
```

Comment: `regexp_replace(format_number(col("Value").cast("double"), 0), ",", "")` can be used to remove the `,`'s added by `format_number`.